# Ubuntu can't find my 2nd Drive during installation, it only sees my 14gb SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I'll be very detailed.
I was running a Windows 10 on my Lenovo Legion y530 system, it has 14gb SSD (which I only found out about after installing Ubuntu) and a 1tb HDD.

I first decided to dual boot Ubuntu 21.04 and Windows, but when I started the installation, Ubuntu said I had to turn off RST. When turning off RST my system warned me I could loose all my data so I backed everything up on another system.

I decided since everything will be wiped I should fully run Ubuntu and not dual boot.

During the installation process I selected the option to wipe out windows and install Ubuntu and it installed.

But after a short while I started getting warning that my disk is full. I checked and saw Ubuntu was installed on a 14gb SSD drive. On checking with 'Drives' I saw that my 1tb disk is still there and I could mount it to access all my files.

I tried reinstalling Ubuntu so I could personally allocate which disk to install on but noticed only the SSD appears.

Please all I need is help to be able to find my HDD during installation, I don't care much for SSD speed, I only want to maximize my space and clean out every trace of Windows

Comment: 14 GB is not big enough for Ubuntu and it's **definitely** not big enough for Windows. If the 1TB hard drive is functioning and it is connected properly, it will show up in the "Disks" application. You can use the same application to format (erase) the disk. Then you can install Ubuntu.  You can use Disks from the live session (Try Ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've been able to format it and now it's in Ext4 format. I'll proceed to do a fresh install of Ubuntu, hopefully this time I'm able to see it. I will get back to you once I do.

Comment: I still don't see it when I try installing, is there a way I can move my root folder to the HDD after installation?

Comment: You don't see it when installing because you already partitioned the drive.  You should only format.  When you create an ext4 file system, there's no free space left.  You need unpartitioned free space to install Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's working now. I am really excited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough unpartitioned free space on the drive, Ubuntu can be easily installed to that space.

One way to do this is to format (erase) the hard drive.

You can use a live session (Try Ubuntu) and use the Disks application to format your disk.  For Ubuntu, it's best if you choose the GPT partition scheme.

After the disk is formatted, you should be able to start the installation and you will be guided through the installation process.  The installer will create the needed partition(s) and file system for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, after erasing it, I created a new partition, using it up. Only then was my installer able to see it.